# Are these duties suitable or sufficient to apply for PR and also under which NOC code?

Tags: immigration, canada, pr

Job Title: Inventory Control Technician

•   Monitor inventory cycle counts.
•   Notify appropriate parties when inventory items need to be ordered according to specific
thresholds and minimum re-order points.
•   Transfer all production logs into the Sage system. This is to be done in defined
intervals throughout the day.
•   Investigate and report any material discrepancies or log errors to supervisors and the
inventory department and, record findings.
•   Sort and file documents according to established filing systems, locate and retrieve
documents from files as requested, and maintain records of filed and removed materials.
•   Maintain and prepare reports from manual or electronic files, inventories, and
databases.
•   Be a backup to the production scheduler and consult with production supervisors to
schedule production in a cost-effective and timely manner.
•   Other duties as required.